# COUNTIFS Counting Duplicate Cells When I Only Want Cells to be only Counted Once

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have this excel formula where I want to count cells that meet this range of criteria. The problem is with this formula, some of the cells meet criteria from multiple countifs, so the formula counts it twice, when it shouldn't.

Here is the formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!P2:P256,"=0",Sheet1!C2:C256,"=3",Sheet1!J2:J256,"<"&M25) + COUNTIFS(Sheet1!P2:P256,"=0",Sheet1!C2:C256,"=3",Sheet1!K2:K256,"<"&N25) + COUNTIFS(Sheet1!P2:P256,"=0",Sheet1!C2:C256,"=3",Sheet1!L2:L256,"<"&O25) + COUNTIFS(Sheet1!P2:P256,"=0",Sheet1!C2:C256,"=3",Sheet1!M2:M256,"<"&P25)
```

I just want to modify it so that it does not count the same cell twice. For example if the cell is counted in the first countifs function, it should not be counted in the next two. I'm assuming there should be an easy fix, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!P2:P256=0)*(Sheet1!C2:C256=3)*((Sheet1!M2:M256<M25)+(Sheet1!M2:M256<N25)+(Sheet1!M2:M256<O25)+(Sheet1!M2:M256<P25)>0))`

Comment: or if you have Office 365: `=COUNT(FILTER(Sheet1!P2:P256,(Sheet1!P2:P256=0)*(Sheet1!C2:C256=3)*((Sheet1!M2:M256<M25)+(Sheet1!M2:M256<N25)+(Sheet1!M2:M256<O25)+(Sheet1!M2:M256<P25)>0)))`

Comment: since your formula have "<"&M25) , "<"&N25, "<"&O25 and "<"&P25 ... combining it as (something like) "<" & max(M25:P25) should do.